# Sent SHIB to the contract address. Is it possible to get it back?

Tags: tokens, metamask, coinbase

hi i have the same issue. Any workaround on this I sent 14,255,725 SHIB from my coinbase exchange account to address: 0x95aD61b0a150d79219dCF64E1E6Cc01f0B64C4cE Which is the SHIB contract address. Accidentally, obviously, I was attempting to send it to my MetaMask wallet and of course I was new and somehow copied the contract address instead of my wallet address.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No unless you ask someone who owns the wallet to send it to you

Comment: +it's shiba inu contract address not "somebodies wallet"

Comment: Same idea, unless you can contact the contract owner and they have the ability to withdraw from contract, and send it thats the only way you can get it.

Comment: @Stackaccount1 In the case of shib, they can't. I'm afraid your tokens are locked there forever, OP.

Comment: +dang, alright well. worth a shot. so what happens to the money? I mean I have other transactions that go to that same address as automatic transaction fees, in my history. Somebody must be able to access it to collect their fees, no?

Comment: I guess if nothing else. I just became part of the shib burn program

Comment: can you mark my answer as correct if possible? ty @Captain.CryptoNaut